# Why the restriction on the length of the proof in a $(r,q)$-verifier in PCP is inconsequential?

Tags: complexity-theory

In the textbook by Arora-Barak, they define PCP verifier as

[image]

While in the definition they put a restriction of $q2^r$on the length of the proof, later, they say that it is inconsequential as the machine can look on at most this number of locations with nonzero probability over all $2^r$ choices for its random string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formal version of "the limitation on the proof length is inconsequential" is the following:

If $L$ has a $(r(n),q(n))$ PCP verifier, then it also has an $(r(n),q(n))$ verifier with proof length bounded by $q(n)2^{r(n)}$.

The above holds since as you mentioned, the verifier can ask $2^{r(n)}q(n)$ different queries on a length $n$ input ($q(n)$ queries for each possible outcome of the verifier coins). Let $f_x$ be an embedding (one to one mapping) of the possible verifier queries on input $x$ in the set $\{1,2,...,q(|x|)2^{r(|x|)}\}$. Let $V'$ be the verifier who acts like $V$, with the sole difference that when $V$ asks for index $i$, $V'$ requests $f_x(i)$. It is easy to see that $V'$ is a verifier for $L$ with the same properties, and bounded length proofs.

Comment: Thanks. I can understand now. I have upvoted but because of having less than 15 reputation it is not showing up.

Comment: No problem. I think you can accept the answer regardless of your reputation (if you want to of course).