# Where is PCP(1,1) located?

Tags: complexity-theory

The PCP-Theorem states that $PCP(log(n), 1) = NP$. So can anyone explain, where $PCP(1,1)$ is located in relation to other classes? 
My thoughts:

$P \subseteq PCP(1,1) \subseteq PCP(log(n)) = NP$
Is there some theorem like "$P \neq NP \implies PCP(1,1) ...$"
What is the relation to the probabilistic classes like $BPP$ and $RP$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$PCP\left(O(1),O(1)\right)=P$.

Suppose you are allowed to toss at most $r$ coins, and that the proof length is bounded by $l\in\mathbb{N}$. Given input $x$, you can compute the acceptance probability of the verifier relative to any proof in $\{0,1\}^{\le l}$. To do this, for every proof $\pi\in\{0,1\}^{\le l}$ and every possible outcome of the random coins $w\in\{0,1\}^r$, simulate $V^{\pi}(x,w)$ and count the number of $w$'s who caused $V^\pi$ to accept. Note that this requires only polynomial time in $|x|$. Now, accept $x$ iff during this process you have found a proof $\pi$ which causes $V$ to accept $x$ with probability $1$.

Note that the constant bound on the proof length does not immediately follow from the definition (in the above you only have a constant bound on the number of queries), but follows from the fact that if $L\in PCP(r(n),q(n))$, then $L$ has proofs of length $\le 2^{r(n)}q(n)$. See [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/84581/why-the-restriction-on-the-length-of-the-proof-in-a-r-q-verifier-in-pcp-is-i) for details.