# Characterization of P in the context of probabilistically checkable proofs

Tags: complexity-theory, probabilistic-algorithms, oracle-machines

The PCP theorem characterizes NP as the class of problems checkable probabilistically using log(n) bits and a constant number of random bits and yields $NP=PCP(O(log(n)),O(1))$ .

Is there a pair $(f,g)$ of functions such that $P=PCP(O(f(n)),O(g(n))$ where $g(n) \ne 0$?  Or is there any research in that direction or an obvious reason why this is a naive approach?

Comment: Please don't use the 'Your Answer' box to provide clarifications or revisions to the question.  Instead, use the link under the question to edit your question and update it, if you realized that you should have asked a different question.  I will make the edit for you this time, but in the future please do so yourself -- and don't use the 'Your Answer' box for anything other than a direct answer to the question.

Comment: I suggest that you register your account and create a password so that you can log in again.  That will provide you the ability to edit your own question and to post comments under your question.  It looks like you created multiple accounts; you might want to [merge them](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: [related](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/87616/where-is-pcp1-1-located)